# How to handle model creep

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

In machine learning, we are constantly updating the models. But we still want a way to use our old trained model checkpoints. These checkpoints will not load if the model class has been changed with different keyword arguments etc.

What's the best way to manage "model creep" or models gradually changing?

One way is, we can associated each pytorch checkpoint with a github commit. Then load that commit to run our model again.

Another way is, every time we change the model, we implement backwards compatibility (could get messy).

Comment: Aside: Nice read about the lack of "picks and shovels" in AI: https://www.forbes.com/sites/robtoews/2020/03/22/a-massive-opportunity-exists-to-build-picks-and-shovels-for-machine-learning/#5daf37ab7ab3. Model creep would be on of the them for sure.

Comment: What do you mean by "using" (I assume the question is strictly about PyTorch's models)? Only inference, training, changing model on the fly after loading, something else?

Comment: @SzymonMaszke Ultimately all of the above. See OpenAI's work where they discuss continually  training a model for months.